# gerrit replication doesn't replicate .repo?

Tags: replication, gerrit

We have a remote repository (Which has .repo and multiple git projects in it)
We want to replicate the same to local server.
With the existing replication.config file
url = gerrit2@15.145.25.168:/home/gerrit2/gerrit_testsite/git/${name}.git

Only the git projects are replicated to local server.
How to replicate .repo . We need the exact replication of the code which is present in the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

.repo cannot be replicated. Replication works only with .git
So make a mirror of the complete repo and then enable replication.